# C# Integration into Windows Shell

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently in the process of developing an application in C#. I am using WPF forms and using an embedded SQLite Database.

I was wondering if it was possible to integrate my program into the windows shell. What I want to be able to do is if a user right clicks on a username or password text field on a website or a piece of software then the right click menu will show options for my program. If the user wants to copy their username from the software I have written then can right click on the field, go to menu 'Retrieve Password Manager Data' > choose the category (software/website) > company names retrieved from the database and then go to copy username or password.

Thanks for your help in this matter.

Comment: I believe this is more of a browser plug-in than integration with windows shell.

Comment: How do you expect this to work in different browsers?

Comment: It is a windows application. If you want to take a look at the current version of the software then feel free to download it at www.boardiesitsolutions.com/DownloadManager if that helps at all what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating a .NET app into the shell without trouble is technically possible since .NET 4.0.  Google IContextMenu to find sample C# code that implements the required COM interface.  Beware of the difficulty of getting it right, debugging is *very* unpleasant.

But that's a long way from what you are asking for, the shell extension handler lets you create a menu entry in the context menu for Explorer windows.  Text boxes in other apps don't expose a standard extensibility interface like the shell does.  It is not quite impossible, it requires injecting code into the app with a windows hook.  But you can't write that kind of code in C#.